# How can I make this css animation smooth

Tags: html, css, css-animations

In the below example you can see the boxes jumping a little bit, How can I make that transition smooth?

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.box {
  background: rgba(0, 10, 103, 0.5);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 10, 103, 0.9);
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: updn 1s infinite ease-out;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
}

@keyframes updn {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(10px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the idea is to make a loop, so the last state should also be the first one, to avoid this jump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask me, *your starting point* at `0%` should begin with `0px`, but that's just me:

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.box {
  background: rgba(0, 10, 103, 0.5);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 10, 103, 0.9);
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: updn 1s infinite ease-out;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
}

@keyframes updn {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the jump between the start and end of the animation is too big and that's causing a jump.

This CSS should improve the smoothness:

```
@keyframes updn {
      0% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      25% {
        transform: translateY(-5px) translateX(5px);
      }
      50% {
        transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(10px);
      }
      75% {
        transform: translateY(-5px) translateX(5px);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
      }
    }
```

This is how it looks:

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.box {
  background: rgba(0, 10, 103, 0.5);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 10, 103, 0.9);
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: updn 1s infinite ease-out;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
}

@keyframes updn {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(-5px) translateX(5px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(10px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateY(-5px) translateX(5px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice try! still needs to be updated, have jumps even on lesser margins

Answer (score 1):

What about this one

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.box {
  background: rgba(0, 10, 103, 0.5);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 10, 103, 0.9);
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: updn 1s infinite ease-out;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
}

@keyframes updn {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(10px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  
  75% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(1px) translateX(10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**1:** You have to start your animation from `transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px)` for smooth transition and

**2:** `transform` value should be same at `0%` and `100%` of keyframes

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.box {
  background: rgba(0, 10, 103, 0.5);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 10, 103, 0.9);
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: updn 1s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
}

@keyframes updn {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(-10px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateY(10px) translateX(10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: **Updated!**, you can try `animation-timing-function: linear;` for more smoothness.

Comment: great, I can see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Increment `animation-delay` on each `.box`, select them using `nth-child()` to add animation-delay individually which was already added,

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.box {
  background: rgba(0, 10, 103, 0.5);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 10, 103, 0.9);
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: updn 1s infinite ease-out;
}
.box:nth-child(2){
  animation-delay:1s; /*This executes after 1st .box thus animation-delay for this should be 1s (i.e. overall animation time) */
}
.box:nth-child(3){
  animation-delay:2s; /*This executes after 2nd .box thus animation-delay for this should be 1s + 1s (i.e. overall animation time + delay of 2nd child) */
}
@keyframes updn {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(10px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This get's you smooth animation, just by changing the delays on each child.

Comment: If you even want an smooth transition when animation end, which at-present jumps to 0 without any transition then for that add animation-direction as alternate, as in this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ft0gc9ne/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll have a look